# Return a default value if an element has an out-of-bounds list index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, error-handling

In **Python 3**, how would you go about returning some default value if you have an out-of-bounds index element? This is a similar question to other threads on here, however, mine is a special case. I want to generate a list of list elements with this property on each element.

I tried like so (*this is a generalization of my code*):

```
list2 = [list1[0][0] or None,
         list1[0][1] or None,
         list1[1][0] or None,
         list1[1][1] or None]
```

**[Note: my indices don't necessarily have a pattern like above]**

I didn't really expect this to work, and it didn't. I get an `IndexError: List index out of range`

I thought potentially a try/except would work, but that only catches when the whole `list2` prompts an IndexError, and not each individual element of `list1`.

My last attempt was doing a bit of both, and creating a function that would call on each of `list1` with a try/except:

```
def checker(element):
    try:
        return element
    except IndexError:
        return None

list2 = [checker(list1[0][0]),
         checker(list1[0][1]),
         checker(list1[1][0]),
         checker(list1[1][1])]
```

I still receive the IndexError, however.

Is there a nice way of accomplishing this? Am I missing something conceptually?

Comment: Also: yes, you are missing something conceptually - checker won't work because the index error happens when resolving the argument to the function, so *the function never gets called*.

Comment: Since it happens when resolving the argument, does that mean my issue is inherently with the list class? Would my most effective route be creating my own list sub-class method?

Comment: *"Most effective"* is something you'll need to work out for your context. It could be a subclass, it could be passing the indices to the function, it could be padding the lists to start with.